# Insert a row in an existing Excel file

Tags: r, excel

How do I insert a row into an Excel file using R? Maybe using some package?

I have looked into xlsx and XLconnect, it seems I can only overwrite instead of insert.

Comment: In XLConnect, add a blank row to your `data.frame` and then save that `data.frame` to your spreadsheet.  If you want to append a second `data.frame`, use the `startRow` parameter.  Set it equal to `nrow(data.frame1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert a new row in an Excel file with the RDCOMClient R package. This approach only works on Windows. An example is provided below.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

dir_Path <- "D:\\"
excel_File <- "test_File.xlsx"
path_Excel_File <- paste0(dir_Path, excel_File)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
nb_Sheets <- Sheets$count() 

Sheets[[1]]$Rows(2)$Insert()
```